# Cannot assert if text is present using Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to assert a PDF by extracting the text from it and then checking whether the text I want is present in the extracted text or not.

The code extracts the PDF properly. The problem is, irrespective of whether the PDF extracted text contains my text or not, the assertion passes.

I am not sure why this is failing.

```
  public static boolean verifyPDFContent(String reqTextInPDF) throws IOException{

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("User/download/test.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println(text);
        Assert.assertTrue (text.equals (reqTextInPDF));
        return text.contains(reqTextInPDF);

    }
```

I call it through:

```
@Then("^I should verify$")
    public void iShouldVerify() throws Throwable {
        export_inspections.verifyPDFContent("z" );
    }
```

Comment: For starters, this code doesn't compile because it has unreachable code.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: I dont think the assertion is passing. Your execution is not even reaching the assertion. You have a `return` statement before the assertion call and thus rendering `Assert.assertTrue()` as dead code.

Comment: I have edited the code now. The assert fails even if the PDF has the text I specify.

Comment: What text gets printed? Anything? Your assert is `.equals()` which unless the text in the PDF is *exactly* "z" and only "z" as you've specified in your code, the assert will always fail.

Comment: I can see "z" getting printed. Is there any wildcard that I can use for not using the exact match?

Comment: No need to use wildcard, you can try with text.contains in the assert like `Assert.assertTrue(text.contains(reqTextInPDF));`

Comment: It works! Can you post it as an answer so that I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
String pdf = "some text contains z inside";
String pdf2 = "some text not contains inside";
System.out.println(pdf.contains("z")); // returns true
System.out.println(pdf2.contains("z")); // returns false
```

so all you need it is to assert if the statement returns true like this:

```
Assert.assertTrue("The pdf doesn't contain needed text", text.contains(reqTextInPDF));
```